# :tag metadata clojure

Tags: clojure, metadata

In the following example (taken from the [Programming Clojure, 2nd ed](http://pragprog.com/book/shcloj2/programming-clojure) book:

```
(defn ^{:tag String} shout [^{:tag String} s] (.toUpperCase s))
```

What is the value of the *:tag* metadata?
Doing a:

```
((map #'shout) :tag)
```

yields **java.lang.String** but what exactly information is conveyed if I can't distinguish between input and output params?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question while reading the third edition of Programming Clojure which has slightly updated example:

```
(defn ^{:tag String} shout [^{:tag String} s] (clojure.string/upper-case s))
```

Which is equivalent to the short form:

```
; I guess tags and type hints are equivalent
(defn ^String shout [^String s] (clojure.string/upper-case s))
```

Like you stated, if you lookup the function metadata it's ambiguous if the tag refers to the input or output param:

```
(meta #'shout)
```

... returns

```
{:tag java.lang.String,
 :arglists ([s]),
 etc... }
```

If you think about it, it has to be the return type since a function can have N arguments but Clojure doesn't allow multiple return values. The :tag in the metadata is not a vector but a single value.

If you actually programmatically needed the tag/type hint of the function arguments, you can call the meta function on the :arglists as shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26116353/695318

Answer (score 0):

> What is the value of the :tag metadata?

I found a clojure official document

[Clojure - Metadata](https://clojure.org/reference/metadata)

```
^String obj - Sets the value of :tag key in the object’s metadata.
Equivalent to ^{:tag java.lang.String} obj
Used to hint an objects type to the Clojure compiler. 
See Java Interop: 
  Type Hints for more information and a complete list of special type hints.
```

[Type Hints](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#typehints)

```
Clojure supports the use of type hints to assist the compiler 
in avoiding reflection in performance-critical areas of code.
```

> what exactly information is conveyed if I can't distinguish between input and output params?

You don't need to specify types for input or output parameters. And, if it's not specified, clojure will execute the function with reflection (according to this description).

And there is an another [blog post](https://kotka.de/blog/2012/06/Did_you_know_IX.html).
According to this post, Clojure is using the IFn interface for all methods created by Clojure code.

```
IFn defines all arguments of .invoke to be of type Object.
So you can pass anything you like to a Clojure function.
It doesn't matter which type it is, because everything is an Object anyway.
```

So, I think to call Clojure methods without type hints and to call Java's reflection `.invoke` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The example from the book Programming Clojure is ambiguous because both function return and parameter are of the same type. A non-ambiguous example would be:

```
(defn ^String strneg [^Double n] (str (- n)))
(meta #'strneg)
; => {:tag java.lang.String, :arglists ([n]), ... ... }
```

Compare with:

```
(meta (first (first (:arglists (meta #'strneg)))))
; => {:tag Double}
```

So when you use meta on a function, tag is a type hint on the return of that function